# How to beat blocking enemies?

Tags: darksiders-3

In Darksiders 3 there are many enemies who can block frontal attacks pretty much forever. So far my best tactic is to dodge around them to attack form behind, but this only works limited and is pretty impossible with multiple enemys around.

Another way I found that work limited is to use the Force Stance, but I really don't like the hammer's moveset which is the reason I would prefer a way to use every weapon.

So is there any better way to deal with these kind of enemies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ways I found to beat blocking enemies, besides the Force Stance, are:

- Whip grab while enemies are not blocking -> a few hit while they are in the air
- Whip knock up
- Chaosform -> attacks ignore blocks
- Flame hollow -> power move burns surrounding enemies
- Attack enemies from behind

If you have other ways to beat these enemies feel free to share them!

Comment: I dodged backwards and then attacked. LB +X I think on PC Xbox pad